# Semantic UI React dropdown inside sidebar opens beyond visibility

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am working on creating a mobile-friendly sidebar for my web app using Semantic UI React. I have a dropdown inside of the sidebar which I would like to open much like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/59174tt1/2/). Currently, the dropdown opens to the right but instead of appearing over the content, the dropdown items appear to the right of the other sidebar content like this:

[image: broken sidebar image]

Here is the code for the sidebar:

```
<Sidebar
    as={Menu}
    animation='push'
    inverted
    onHide={this.handleSidebarHide}
    vertical
    visible={sidebarOpened}
    style={{"overflow": "visible"}}
>
    <Menu.Item
        onClick={this.handleToggle}
        exact
        as={NavLink}
        to="/home"
        name='home'
    />
    <ClassesDropdown />
    <Menu.Item
        onClick={this.handleToggle}
        as={NavLink}
        to="/profile"
        name='my profile'
    />
    <Menu.Item
        onClick={this.handleToggle}
        as={NavLink}
        to="/leaderboard"
        name='leaderboard'
    />
    <Menu.Item
        onClick={this.handleToggle}
        as={NavLink}
        to="/search"
        name='search'
    />
</Sidebar>
```

What the ClassesDropdown component renders:

```
<Dropdown item text={"Classes"} direction="down" simple>
    <Dropdown.Menu>
         <Dropdown.Item as={NavLink} exact to={`/feed/`} key={0}>
            All Classes
         </Dropdown.Item>
         <Dropdown.Item as={NavLink} exact to={`/feed/2`} key={1}>
             "AP Human Geography"
         </Dropdown.Item>
         <Dropdown.Item as={NavLink} exact to={`/feed/1`} key={2}>
             "Algebra 2/Trig C"
         </Dropdown.Item>
    </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
```

As suggested in the fiddle linked above, I tried adding `style={{"overflow": "visible"}}` but I got the same result.

Comment: When I have issues with dropdowns not positioning how I'd like, I usually end up just using a popup, though that's not without it's own issues you have to work through.

Comment: I used the popup and it worked well - thank you